# Can't disconnect BLE devices when killing the app with background plugin on

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm developing an app that interfaces with BLE devices using [this plugin](https://github.com/evothings/cordova-ble).
Inside the app, I can pair the devices and monitor their status.
If I close the app I want to disconnect the devices from the smartphone, and when I open it again, I want the app to reconnect automatically to known devices.

Everything works fine without using the [background plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode), but I need to use it since the app needs to monitor the BLE devices even when it's in the background.

The problem happens ONLY if I use the background plugin: if I open again the app, the known devices are not reconnected INSIDE the app, but it appears they are already/still connected to the smartphone from the previous time (even if not shown in the Bluetooth devices in the phone settings).
It seems that the Bluetooth connection to known devices isn't really being closed when I kill the app.
It appears like the device is still connected as therefore it doesn't show up when I scan in the app.

I can't reconnect until I close the app, switch off and then on again Bluetooth, and reopen the app.

The steps are very simples:

1. I open and connect the first time from the phone to the BLE product
2. Communication is OK, data is sent and received
3. I close (kill) the application from the smartphone (Without turning off Bluetooth/BLE from smartphone)
4. I relaunch the application ---> Known device is not reconnected but appears to be somehow still paired with the phone (if I press the pairing button it does not go into pairing mode, that happens if it is already bonded to a phone).

Why this behavior? Looks like something in the background plugin prevents the Bluetooth connection to be closed on app closing. I specify that:

- it only occurs using the background plugin, without it activated everything works ok
- this behavior occurs only with Android (don't use the background plugin for iOS)
- it does happen only on some Android smartphones: tried three different phones, with Android version v4.4, v5.1.1, and v6.0.1, and only two of them show this issue (android version 4.4 on S3 and 6.0.1 on S5 Neo).

Thanks

Comment: How exactly do you "kill the app"?

Comment: plz post your code and tell us at what point u are facing the issue?

Comment: @Emil by "kill" I mean I manually swipe out and close the app.

Comment: Swipe away an activity in the app does not mean the process gets killed; it only destroys that activity. If you only have one component like one activity, then yes the process will also be killed. But if you also have a foreground service running like the background plugin sets up, the process is not killed. You need to go to app settings, find the app and press "force stop". Or in Android studio if you have connected the phone you can press the red "Terminate Application" button in the left sidebar of "Android Monitor".

Comment: @Emil you are totally right.
I found out that forcing the closure of the app in the settings solve the problem, and when I open again the app everything works.
I believe then that it is a problem of a service (probably the one created by the background plugin), which is somehow not stopped when I swipe away the app.
I tried to add the stopWithTask = "true" in the Android Manifest, but this doesn't force the service to stop when I swipe away the app!
How can this happen? Do you have any suggestion about that, or things I must be aware of when trying to close a service together with the app?

Comment: Can it be that the service is not "binded" to the app, and therefore it doesn't see the stopWithTask when I close the app?

Comment: The whole point of having a foreground service running in the background is to not kill the process when an activity is not active. What do you try to achieve? If you simply want to disconnect the BLE devices when you close the activity, you must make sure you call .disconnect() and .close() on the GATT objects when the activity is closed.

Comment: We are using background plugin exactly for that, to be sure that the activity keeps running when it is in background.
The problem is that it seems that the background service is not terminated when the app is killed (swiped out from task manager), so when we open again the app we are not able to connect again to the known devices (which are somehow still connected to the previous app opening).
We only can reconnect by either:
- force closure of the app from the settings (which also close all the services)
- close the app, manually switch off the bluetooth, enable it again and open the app

Comment: We must therefore find a way to close all the services with the activity ONLY when the app is swiped away and killed. If we don't close the services the devices remain "bonded" and we cannot reconnect the second time we open the app.
But even if we tried to use stopWithTask = "true" in the AndroidManifest, and onTaskRemoved (where we placed stopService), the problem isn't solved.
How can we close the service when we swipe the app? Is there an error we are making using those functions? We must do something in Cordova?

Comment: Btw I'm using Cordova, not full native, but the problem is that I cannot stop the background service created by the [background plugin](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) neither by using stopWithTask nor with onTaskRemoved. I really can't understand why they are not working, they should do the job!

Comment: @Emil we managed to enter into "onTaskRemoved" by using stopWithTask = "false" in the AndroidManifest (don't know why it wasn't working before).
The problem is that using stopService() inside onTaskRemoved is not working. It enters into the function onTaskRemoved, but doesn't execute the stopService(). Any idea?